# Were there examples from Renaissance period of a relationship of erotic nature between a teacher and a student or during transmission of knowledge?

Tags: education, sexuality, sex

The context for my question is drawn from a movie on teaching history. The question per se, pertains to history. I hope that it was triggered by a movie scene is only seen as a context and not as a diversion.

In the [2006 movie "The History Boys](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_History_Boys_(film))", at the 53rd minute, the following scene occurs. The headmaster is scolding the teacher Hector, for abuse. The teacher seems indifferent to the scolding for the most part. He makes a feeble attempt to defend himself by saying:

> "The transmission of knowledge is in itself an erotic act".

Then, he is about to substantiate it by starting to say:

> "In the Renaissance......"

The headmaster abruptly cuts him off by saying: "*Hell with your renaissance, the literature, Plato, Michael Angelo and Oscar Wilde*". (I have slightly edited the exact text of cutting off to avoid unparliamentary words used by the headmaster).

The question is : Say, Hector was allowed to continue his statement that began with "*In Renaissance...*", what examples of personalities or historical episodes could he have quoted to substantiate the view that teaching as an activity may have an erotic angle to it ? Did the view exist at all ? Were there examples of this at all during the Renaissance period ? If yes, what were they ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alan Bennett was [interviewed](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/culture/theatre/drama/3619379/The-truth-behind-the-History-Boys.html) about the play The History Boys by the Telegraph. In the interview he was asked explicitly about that phrase. He replied:

> The phrase actually comes from George Steiner – I asked his permission to use it – and it comes from his latest book called [Lessons of the Masters](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iLJffLgHHvMC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Steiner talks about the whole question of sexuality and teaching, and though I'd written the play before I'd read it I was heartened that some of the things – for instance the notion that Irwin's teaching is sexualised by the pupil who actually takes it all on board – wasn't just an idea I'd had, but can occur as part of the nature of teaching.

As far as I can see, Bennett seems to have paraphrased from Steiner, rather than quoting verbatim.